# C# OpenPop.net Getting attachments from a E-mail

Tags: c#, email, attachment, openpop

I'm here asking if it is possible to list all the attachments in a E-mail, show them in a list box, and only retrive them (on a program in the OS that opens that extension) once the user clicks on it.

If it's possible, please explain how. I'm using OpenPop.net and C#.

Thanks in advance.

João Borrego.

Answer (score -1):

You certainly can.

Use the [`Message.FindAllAttachments`](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/OpenPop~OpenPop.Mime.Message.FindAllAttachments.html) method to get a `List<MessagePart>` referencing each attachment in the `Message`.  You might use the [`MessagePart.FileName`](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/OpenPop~OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart.FileName.html) property to populate your ListBox (beware of duplicate names however).

I'm not sure how you'd download an attachment through a user's interaction with a ListBox.  Some ideas come to mind but in general you can download attachments using the [File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) method, passing in the [`Message.Body`](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/OpenPop~OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart.Body.html) property for the method's `bytes` argument.

I recently used [OpenPop](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/examples.php) in a project and was pleased with it.

Comment: To use Message.FindAllAttachments method you need to download message from server and user ask how to get attachment file names without downloading the whole attachment. I do not find a way in latest 2.0.4.369 version to find out attachment data without downloading the whole message. OpenPop is not flexible in this case.